# How to parse 6-digit hexadecimal integer from String in dart?

Tags: dart, parsing, colors, hex

I can't find a way to parse a string like '0xFFBBD1F0' to the integer 0xFFBBD1F0. Actually I just need to create a Color having only '0xFFBBD1F0' string.

I needed to create a Color from String I got from the server that looks like 'FFFFFF'. The Colors are usually created like Color(0xFFFFFFFF). So I wrote a code to add '0xFF' to the part I got from server and used int.parse method. Than I tried another combinations of this method, with radix argument and without, I tried somehow change the String I pass to int.parse, but nothing worked. While trying I only got a number, for example, 4290499056 or a FormatException.

The code example:

```
void main() {
  String data = '0xFFBBD1F0';
  var cl = int.parse(data, radix: 16);
  print(cl);
}
```

Believe the code above should work correctly, but I get this:
`Uncaught Error: FormatException: 0xFFBBD1F0`

Changing code to:

```
void main() {
  String data = '0xFFBBD1F0';
  var cl = int.parse(data);
  print(cl);
}
```

only leads me to the output value:
`4290499056`
when I want to get 0xFFBBD1F0.

So is that possible in dart to convert the String '0xFFBBD1F0' to the int 0xFFBBD1F0? And if it is, than how? If it is not, is there a way to create a color having only 'BBD1F0' String as an input?

Comment: 4290499056 *is* the same number as 0xFFBBD1F0.  Are you unfamiliar with number bases?

Comment: I do know about number bases. Somehow I didn't thought I could put to the color constructor a number like 4290499056. Someone could think like I did for some time and this question may be helpful at least in saving time. Also I still can't see what I did wrong in using int.parse, so I was hoping somebody tell me why it didn't work as expected. However, the title of my question is not about creating a color.

Comment: This question "So is that possible in dart to convert the String '0xFFBBD1F0' to the int 0xFFBBD1F0?" tells me you don't understand number bases.  You *did* the conversion, and got 4290499056 decimal, which *is* a number you could hand in as Color(4290499056) and get the color you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very complex and non-trivial task.
Try this code.

```
void main() {
  String data = '0xFFBBD1F0';
  // So is that possible in dart to convert the String '0xFFBBD1F0' to the int 0xFFBBD1F0?
  // And...
  // ...convert the String '0xFFBBD1F0' to the int 0xFFBBD1F0
  var cl = int.parse(data);
  print(cl);
  // Yes!!! It works!
  print(cl == 0xFFBBD1F0);
  print('0x${cl.toRadixString(16).toUpperCase()}');
}
```

Output:

```
4290499056
true
0xFFBBD1F0
```